# Invalid signature error for ROS repository while trying to do sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt

This is the error that I am getting

```
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG F42ED6FBAB17C654 Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG F42ED6FBAB17C654 Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to re-add the mentioned GPG key to the system by using command below

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

Comment: It says `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure`

Answer (score 1):

This means that the repo keys have not been set up correctly.
You cann add them again with the command below.

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

See ROS installation instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu